# Почему Unable to start activity ComponentInfo при LogIn Facebook?

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь сделать регистрацию с помощью facebook... [нашел пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myWu-q8Q2NA) и вот по нему делаю, единственное только различие, что в примере показано как кнопку поставить во фрагмент, а я делаю без фрагмента. Библиотеку имплементировал, пермишны прописал, все сделал и все загружается и показывает, но как только в XML файл вставляю кнопку которую дает сам facebook

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view,
                    "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

то все вылетает с ошибкой

> -03 10:30:25.748 30649-30649/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   05-03 10:30:25.788 30649-30649/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
>   05-03 10:30:25.788 30649-30649/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
>   05-03 10:30:25.868 30649-30649/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin-1/base.apk
>   05-03 10:30:25.968 30649-30649/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin D/KeyHash:: 1tY8plXu6Ae5AiW2u5nfNxuAkoA=
>   05-03 10:30:26.208 30649-30649/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   05-03 10:30:26.248 30649-30649/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/com_facebook_button_icon_blue.png
>   05-03 10:30:26.258 30649-30649/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/com_facebook_button_icon_white.png
>   05-03 10:30:26.268 30649-30649/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   05-03 10:30:26.268 30649-30649/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin, PID: 30649
>                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin/com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>                                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
>                                                                                           at com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
>                                                                                           at com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
>                                                                                        Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
>                                                                                           at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:145)
>                                                                                           at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
>                                                                                           at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.(LoginButton.java:563)
>                                                                                           at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:563)
>                                                                                           at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.(FacebookButtonBase.java:69)
>                                                                                           at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.(LoginButton.java:201)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:933) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
>                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
>                                                                                           at com.stoun.life.first.facebooklogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Что я нужно добавить или поменять, чтоб не вылетала ошибка?

Comment: Кажется, что не вся инфа из логов у вас в вопросе... И если кнопку убрать то всё работает?

Comment: Код активити еще бы посмотреть

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил полный лог... Да если кнопку удаляю то все работает...(( Так самое главное, что я скачал с гита тот пример который обьясняется и запустил у себя на девайсе и ничего не вылетает, так он еще там 2 кнопки сделал 1 кастом, другая стандартная и все работает... Но у него пример с фрагментами... Думаю может в них дело...

Comment: @qwerty123 добавил полное описание

Answer (score 1):

Нашел проблему! Все дело было в том, что в видео примере он обьясняет что вот эту строчку

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

нужно писать в `MainActivity`

Но на самом деле она должна быть описана в том активити в котором мы получаем хэш ключ, (это другое активити которое мы создаем делаем ему `extend Application` и добавляем его в файл манифеста сразу после этой строчки

```
<application
```

Когда я перенес эту строку все заработало